# How to serialize a delegate

Tags: c#, serialization, delegates

Lets look at an example of grid filling.

We have **Column** class. It has a delegate **FormatCell**, which take some **Data** and convert it to a **string**. **FormatCell** delegate is unknown at design time - it might be set by a plugin.

```
public class ColumnFormatter
{
    public Func<Data, string> FormatCell {get; set;}
    //...
}
```

Here is an example of how such Columns are used.

```
public class Table
{
    public List<Column> Columns;

    public List<List<string>> BuildTable(List<Data> dataRows)
    {
        var table = new List<List<string>>();

        foreach (var data in dataRows)
        {
            var line = new List<string>();                    
            foreach (var column in Columns)
            {
                line.Add(column.FormatCell(data));
            }

            table.Add(line);
        }

        return table;
    }
}
```

Now each column should save its state. And the question is how to serialize this FormatCell delegate?

P.S. I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346111/is-it-possible-to-serialize-a-c-sharp-code-block) but my question is much more case specific. And maybe one has a specific reliable run-in solution for the such case?

Comment: It's supported, delegate objects are binary serializable.  It is entirely unclear why you are having a problem with it or what kind of serialization you want to use or why you need it or if you've even tried to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't just use inheritance? And not to try serialize delegate. Something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class ColumnFormatterBase
{
    public abstract string FormatCell(Data data);
}

[Serializable]
public class ColumnFormatter1: ColumnFormatterBase
{
    object SerializableProperty1 {get; set;}
    object SerializableProperty2 {get; set;}
    public override string FormatCell(Data data)
    {
        return // formatted result //;
    }
}
```

It can be serialized, even if implementation of ColumnFormatterBase is located somewhere in plugin assembly.